# Error: Got unexpected extra arguments when using Click library

Tags: python, command-line-interface, python-click

I'm trying to use the Click library in Python to create a command line interface, but I keep getting the following error when I try to run my script:

```
Error: Got unexpected extra arguments (hello hello1)
```

Here is my code:

```
import click

@click.group(name='script')
def cli():
    pass

@cli.command()
def hello1():
    click.echo('Hello, World!')

@cli.command()
def hello2():
    click.echo('Hola, Mundo!')

@cli.command()
@click.argument('function', type=click.Choice(['hello1', 'hello2']))
def hello(function):
    if function == 'hello1':
        hello1()
    elif function == 'hello2':
        hello2()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cli()
```

I'm trying to call the "hello" function with the argument "hello1" or "hello2", but it's not working. Can anyone help me figure out what's going wrong?

```
python script.py hello hello1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you've written your code, you shouldn't be defined `hello1` and `hello2` as commands. If you simply remove the decorator, your code works as written. That is, given:

```
import click

@click.group(name='script')
def cli():
    pass

def hello1():
    click.echo('Hello, World!')

def hello2():
    click.echo('Hola, Mundo!')

@cli.command()
@click.argument('function', type=click.Choice(['hello1', 'hello2']))
def hello(function):
    if function == 'hello1':
        hello1()
    elif function == 'hello2':
        hello2()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cli()
```

We can run:

```
$ python script.py hello hello1
Hello, World!
$ python script.py hello hello2
Hola, Mundo!
```

If you want `hello1` and `hello2` to be subcommands of `hello`, then you would need to redefine `hello` as a [command group](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/8.1.x/commands/), like this:

```
import click

@click.group(name='script')
def cli():
    pass

@cli.group()
def hello():
    pass

@hello.command()
def hello1():
    click.echo('Hello, World!')

@hello.command()
def hello2():
    click.echo('Hola, Mundo!')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    cli()
```

This supports the same command lines, but instead of explicitly testing for an argument we rely on `click` to dispatch the appropriate command.